# Android -- SpannableStringBuilder not affecting TextView

Tags: android, textview, superscript, spannable

I'm trying make a registered trademark symbol into a superscript with the following code:

```
public static void formatSuperscript(TextView itemTitle) {
    String title = itemTitle.getText().toString();
    SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(title);
    for (int i = 0; i < title.length(); i++) {
        if (title.charAt(i) == '®') {
            sb.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), i, i + 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            sb.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.75f), i, i + 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
    itemTitle.setText(sb);
}
```

The custom font I'm using displays the registered trademark as a normal character.  From log statements, I know the if statement is getting triggered properly.  Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried setting the flag to SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE ?

Comment: Yes. This did not work either.

Comment: Is the TextView using allCaps mode (see [Issue 67509](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67509))?

Comment: Wow, that's it. Thanks a lot!